# spring replaced bean by instance of cglib generated class

Tags: java, spring, cglib, spring-bean

At the some moment(I mean it can works fine for a few days-weeks) in my app spring replaced my autowired bean(which was wrapped by proxy) to instance of class which has been generated by cglib(after replace the issue reproduce every time).
It reproduce only for me(for another 40 people in my team didn't. the difference only in: I'm used Linux and related soft).
This generated class haven't any methods which have original class.
I mean:

```
@Component
public class CFlowHandlerImpl extends CFlowHandlerImpl implements InitializingBean{
..
    @Autowired
    private JobProcessingDao jobProcessingDao;//corrupted
    @Autowired
    private NameTemplateDao nameTemplateDao;
..
}
```

package.JobProcessingDaoImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$91f585b0@76401ef6
package.NameTemplateDaoImpl@1620dc5b

To fix this I can just clone project again(remove .m2 didn't help), but I just want to know why this happens and how to avoid it.

- spring: 3.1.4
- java:1.8.0_60
- linux:3.11.0-12-generic
- maven 3.2.5
- tomcat 7.0.30